# question about basis and dimensions

Tags: vector-spaces

if $U$ and $V$ are 2-dimensional vector spaces over 4-tuples of real numbers then what will be the dimensions of $U+V$?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

For example, what is the answer if $U=V$? What about if $U = \{(x,y,0,0)\}$ and $V = \{(0,0,x,y)\}$?